# MYSQL: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails Struggling to add user to group of users

Tags: mysql

i keep struggling to figure out why i cant seem to add users.  Is it a database setup issue? or just a syntax issue?  Need some guidance.

When trying to simply insert in an existing user_id to and existing room_id i keep getting

Query:

```sql
INSERT INTO group_users (room_id, user_id) VALUES(1, 3);
```

`ERROR: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

both the user id and the room id exist in the database already.  Wondering what i need to do.

for reference here is the database schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `room_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`room_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `room_name` (`room_name`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;


-- Chatapp.users definition

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(32) DEFAULT 'english',
  `SocketID` varchar(42) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registered_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `confirmed_email` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `confirmed_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;


-- Chatapp.group_users definition

CREATE TABLE `group_users` (
  `room_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`room_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `group_users_fk2` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `group_users_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`room_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`room_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `group_users_fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


-- Chatapp.messages definition

CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `message_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`message_id`),
  KEY `messages_fk1` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `messages_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I changed `group_id` to `room_id` it's work normally now:

```
CREATE TABLE `group_users` (
  `room_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`room_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `group_users_fk2` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `group_users_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`room_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`room_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `group_users_fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `username`, `language`, `SocketID`, `email`, `password`, `registered_on`, `confirmed_email`, `confirmed_on`) VALUES (NULL, 'pavel', 'english', NULL, NULL, NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '0', NULL);
INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `username`, `language`, `SocketID`, `email`, `password`, `registered_on`, `confirmed_email`, `confirmed_on`) VALUES (NULL, 'bob', 'english', NULL, NULL, NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '0', NULL);
INSERT INTO `groups` (`room_id`, `room_name`) VALUES (NULL, 'room1');
INSERT INTO `groups` (`room_id`, `room_name`) VALUES (NULL, 'room2');
INSERT INTO `group_users` (`room_id`, `user_id`) VALUES ('1', '2');
INSERT INTO `group_users` (`room_id`, `user_id`) VALUES ('1', '1');
```

result:

```
+---------+---------+
| room_id | user_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
|       1 |       2 |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: it still gives me 
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Chatapp`.`group_users`, CONSTRAINT `group_users_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`room_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`room_id`))

Comment: I add table definition which I used from your source. I try add values to users and groups(rooms) and insert to group_users works fine.

Comment: I just did and it works perfectly fine.  I have no idea what i managed to screw up in my database, quite frustrating.  Might dump the data and redo the DB at this point

Comment: Ah, i just figured it out! Somehow one of the foreign key constraints dropped, which caused the error!  Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Is `rooms` the same as `groups`? Note that there is no `room_id` in `groups`-table as your constraint suggest.

Comment: ahh yes, I just edited the post!  Sorry, it is infact room_id in the table